# how to prove unobservable subspace ($\text{null}(C, A)$) is $A$-invariant

Tags: control-theory

Given
$$ \begin{align*}
\dot{x} &= Ax + Bu \\
y &= Cx
\end{align*} $$
where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, $C \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n}$.

How to prove the title?

I think I should use the matrix:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}C \\ CA \\ \vdots \\ CA^{n-1} \end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: I've taken the liberty to edit your post. Please have a look in case something is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

$$ \mathcal{O} = \begin{bmatrix}C \\ CA \\ \vdots \\ CA^{n-1} \end{bmatrix} $$

We need to show that if $v \in \text{Ker} \mathcal{O}$, then $Av \in \text{Ker} \mathcal{O}$. If $v \in \text{Ker} \mathcal{O}$, then

$$ \begin{bmatrix}C \\ CA \\ \vdots \\ CA^{n-1} \end{bmatrix} v = \begin{bmatrix}Cv \\ CAv \\ \vdots \\ CA^{n-1}v \end{bmatrix} = 0 $$

Now, let us look at $\mathcal{O} A v$, which is

$$ \begin{bmatrix}CA \\ CA^2 \\ \vdots \\ CA^{n} \end{bmatrix} v = \begin{bmatrix}CAv \\ CA^2v \\ \vdots \\ CA^{n}v \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ CA^{n}v \end{bmatrix} $$

The last term is also $0$ because of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.